# Given an offset dictionary and a string, create the BIO tags

Tags: python, string, offset, character-replacement

Given (i) a string `text` and (ii) a dictionary made of offset and the substring `y`:

```
text = "\u5723\u4f9d\u534e\u5802'\"\uff08\uff09\u662f\u4e00\u5ea7\u4f4d\u4e8e\u610f\u5927\u5229\u7f57\u9a6c\u7684\u7f57\u9a6c\u5929\u4e3b\u6559\u6559\u5802\u3002\u8fd9\u5ea7\u6559\u5802\u88ab\u8ba4\u4e3a\u662f\u5df4\u6d1b\u514b\u6559\u5802\u5efa\u7b51\u7684\u6770\u4f5c\uff0c\u7531\u5efa\u7b51\u5e08\u5f17\u6717\u5207\u65af\u79d1\u00b7\u535a\u7f57\u7c73\u5c3c\u4fee\u5efa\u4e8e1642\u81f31660\u5e74\u3002\n\u5386\u53f2.\n\u8fd9\u5ea7\u6559\u5802\u59cb\u5efa\u4e8e14\u4e16\u7eaa\uff0c\u5f53\u65f6\u662f\u4f5c\u4e3a\u7f57\u9a6c\u4e0a\u667a\u5927\u5b66\u5bab\u7684\u5c0f\u6559\u5802\u3002\u8fd9\u6240\u5927\u5b66\u88ab\u79f0\u4e3a\u4e0a\u667a\uff08\"La Sapienza\"\uff09\uff0c\u800c\u8fd9\u5ea7\u6559\u5802\u4f9b\u5949\u7684\u662f\u5723\u4f9d\u534e\uff08Saint Yves\uff0c\u6cd5\u5b66\u5bb6\u7684\u4e3b\u4fdd\u5723\u4eba\uff09\uff0c\u56e0\u800c\u5f97\u540d\u3002\u6ce2\u7f57\u7c73\u5c3c\u88ab\u8feb\u4f7f\u4ed6\u7684\u8bbe\u8ba1\u9002\u5e94\u73b0\u6709\u7684\u5bab\u6bbf\u3002\u4ed6\u9009\u62e9\u4e00\u4e2a\u7c7b\u4f3c\u4e8e\u5927\u536b\u4e4b\u661f\u7684\u89c4\u5212\uff0c\u5c06\u6559\u5802\u7684\u7acb\u9762\u4e0e\u5bab\u6bbf\u7684\u5ead\u9662\u5408\u5e76\u3002\u5176\u7a79\u9876\u6709\u4e00\u4e2a\u975e\u5e38\u65b0\u9896\u7684\u87ba\u65cb\u5f62\u9876\u5854\u3002\u5185\u90e8\u4ee4\u4eba\u773c\u82b1\u7f2d\u4e71\u7684\u51e0\u4f55\u4f53\u6784\u6210\u590d\u6742\u7684\u97f5\u5f8b\u3002\u8fd9\u662f\u4e00\u5ea7\u7406\u6027\u7684\u5efa\u7b51- \u770b\u8d77\u6765\u5f88\u7eb7\u4e71\uff0c\u4f46\u662f\u5176\u5e73\u9762\u91cd\u53e0\u7740\u4e00\u5708\u5708\u4e24\u4e24\u53e0\u52a0\u7684\u7b49\u8fb9\u4e09\u89d2\u5f62\uff0c\u5728\u4e00\u5ea7\u96c6\u4e2d\u7684\u6559\u5802\u5185\uff0c\u6784\u6210\u4e00\u5217\u516d\u89d2\u5f62\u5c0f\u6559\u5802\u548c\u796d\u53f0\u7684\u57fa\u7840\u3002\u5185\u90e8\u7684\u51f9\u51f8\u8d77\u4f0f\uff0c\u5f62\u6210\u4e0d\u548c\u8c10\u7136\u800c\u4f7f\u4eba\u7729\u6655\u7684\u9b45\u529b\u3002\u88c5\u9970\u662f\u516d\u7ffc\u5929\u4f7f\u5934\u50cf\u548c\u51e0\u4f55\u4f53\uff08\u661f\u661f\uff09\u7684\u7ec4\u5408\uff0c\u6bd4\u8d77\u540c\u65f6\u4ee3\u7684\u6d4e\u5b89\u00b7\u8d1d\u5c3c\u5c3c\u8fc7\u5ea6\u4f7f\u7528\u9540\u91d1\u548c\u77f3\u818f\uff0c\u8f83\u4e3a\u67cf\u62c9\u56fe\u3002\u6cbf\u4e09\u6839\u5706\u9876\u652f\u67f1\u57fa\u7840\u5411\u4e0a\uff0c\u662f\u6559\u5b97\u4e9e\u6b77\u5c71\u5927\u4e03\u4e16\u7684\u57fa\u5409\u5bb6\u65cf\u6807\u5fd7\u201c\u4e00\u9897\u661f\u661f\u4e0b\u65b9\u7684\u516d\u5ea7\u5c71\u201d\u3002"

y = {16: '罗马', 19: '罗马天主教', 24: '教堂', 35: '巴洛克', 
     50: '弗朗切斯科·博罗米尼', 96: '罗马上智大学', 142: '圣依华', 
     199: '大卫之星', 376: '济安·贝尼尼', 413: '亞歷山大七世', 420: '基吉家族'}
```

To see the raw `text` : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alvations/4c3460cf2dda5e19d828a8bace532216/raw/28190258c2be8ed7123033e77edefbf9201e1845/text

The goal is to iterate through all the characters in the `text` and then print

- `O` if the character is **Outside**/not in the substring dictionary
- `B` if the character is the **Beginning**/start of a substring in the dictionary
- `I` if the character is **Inside**/part of a substring in the dictionary

I've tried this which produces the expected output:

```
bio = []
bi_end = 0

for i, ch in enumerate(text):
    if i in y:
        bio.append('B')
        bi_end = i + len(y[i])
    elif i < bi_end:
        bio.append('I')
    else:
        bio.append('O')
```

Which kind of worked and produced:

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'B', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'B', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Or in string:

```
>>> ''.join(bio)
'OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIOBIIIIBIOOOOOOOOOBIIOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIIIIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOBIIIIIOBIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO'
```

But is there a simpler to achieve the same desired output? **Maybe with some regex and replacement?**

**Or some special `str.translate` table operation?**

Answer (score 1):

This problem is about ranges, rather than characters.
You wrote `{16: '罗马', 19: '罗马天主教', ...`
but it could as easily have been

```
y = {16: 'xx', 19: 'xxxxx', ...
```

or

```
y = {16: 2, 19: 5, ...
```

The algorithm you supplied looks great.
First case exploits a data structure that
offers O(1) constant time access, and
the other two cases are even simpler.
You need to produce N output characters,
and you have a O(N) linear time algorithm.
`re` and `.translate()` won't offer improvements on that.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime can be improved by iterating over your substring dictionary instead, since the input text doesn't appear to really matter. (And exit early once key index exceeds input text size.)

Just as an example, esp since the substring dict is already sorted by index, consider how your example's first key is 16. You're guaranteed for the first 16 output chars to be `O` without even checking the text.

The runtime of this is `min(O(n), O(m))` for length of text n and size of dict m. (Though technically as stated you lose the savings by outputting n chars for output.)

Comment: Runtime will not be O(min(n, m)). Why? Consider a `text` of a million characters and `y = {16: '罗马'}`. Correct output is approximately a million `O`utside characters. Does it take time proportional to `len(y)` to produce that? No, `len(text)` will dominate. Of course generating much of the output with `"O" * 1_000_000` will take less wallclock time, but that's a matter of implementation, it's still an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: I consider that a technicality b/c I could have this procedure return in O(m) by lazily returning the solution in principle, incurring the cost of materialization on read later. And yes, it is also more efficient in practice.

Comment: I'm not here to criticize the OP output spec; I just conform to it.